# DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION by

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've: DENSE_RANK() OVER (  PARTITION BY state ORDER BY population desc) as ranking

I'd like to skip the first 10 results of my ranking and limit it to 50 results per state. Is this possible?

Comment: do you mean you want to avoid the results `1-10` or the first 10 rows which dense-rank cannot give you (in the occurrence of duplicates)

Comment: but HAVING or QUALIFY is the normal method to add a extra clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so:

```
with data(state, pop) as (
    select * from values 
    (1,10),
    (1,10),
    (1,11),
    (1,12),
    (2,10),
    (2,11),
    (2,12),
    (2,12)
)
select d.*
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY state ORDER BY pop desc) as ranking
from data as d
```

gives:

| STATE | POP | RANKING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | 12 | 1 |
| 2 | 11 | 2 |
| 2 | 10 | 3 |
| 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 1 | 11 | 2 |
| 1 | 10 | 3 |
| 1 | 10 | 3 |

so we can use QAULIFY to only keep those >= 3 to avoid the first "2"

```
select d.*
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY state ORDER BY pop desc) as ranking
from data as d
qualify ranking >= 3
```

| STATE | POP | RANKING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 | 3 |
| 1 | 10 | 3 |
| 1 | 10 | 3 |

but this shows, as we had 4 per set, we have removed 2,3 respectively from the two sets.

This can also be down with the DENSE_RANK in the QUALIFY like:

```
select d.*
from data as d
qualify DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY state ORDER BY pop desc) >= 3
```

| STATE | POP |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 10 |

thus skipping the 10's and take things up to the 50's can be done with:

```
qualify DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY state ORDER BY pop desc) between 10 and 50
```

but if you really want the absolute first 10 skipped and 50 or less rows, you should use a non-duplicating rank like ROW_NUMBER, thus to skip 10 and take make 50 per state:

```
qualify ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by state order by pop desc) between 10 and 60
```